# Dispatch / generate keydown event in Vanilla JS (no jQuery, use Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

How can I simulate a keypress to an input, ***using vanilla javascript***?

I have tested every possible answer on SO and elsewhere, and it doesn't work on Chrome or Firefox.

For example, let's say we have a form:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button id="myButton>Click Me</button>
```

How could I make it so that when the button is clicked, the letter "a" is added to the input?

Comment: What *exactly* have you tried? Please show your code.

Comment: Do you need the keypress event as well? If not, Carls' solution is enough. If you actually have need for the event object ( so you can check things like `event.keyCode` and such ), you'll have to create the event yourself and dispatch it.

Comment: [tag:vanilla-javascript] is already a synonym for [tag:javascript]. No need to create another one.

Comment: @str what I already tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically

https://elgervanboxtel.nl/site/blog/simulate-keydown-event-with-javascript

Answer (score 3):

You'd first add a keyup event listener to the `document` object and inside the callback you assign the value of the input via [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Value) depending on which key was pressed:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 39 || e.which === 19) {
    input.value += 'a';
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" />

<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: since OP asked for an example where you add an "a" you should replace "input.value = 'a';" with "input.value += 'a';". Otherwise your just setting the value.

Still upvoted as best answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes this way would work, however I am trying to simulate an actual keypress. Specifically, I want to press the "right arrow" key. This method wouldn't work in that case. 

Is there any way to actually dispatch a keypress with the desired kecode? For example, for ArrowRight, it would be 19 (www.keycode.info)

Comment: yea...gimme a sec.

Comment: hey @CarlEdwards did you manage to find a solution for this at all? :)

Comment: Can you explain to me one more time what you want? From what I collect, you wanna trigger the keyup event from clicking the button, correct? Did you also want there to be a keyup event as well. Or is the functionality geared solely towards the button?

Comment: Sure! Basically I want to make the click of a button trigger a keydown for the right arrow key. So, "click this button" would move the cursor of the input field along by one position. Specifically, I have an input field that has emojis in it, so setting the cursor position with setSelectionRange doesn't work, because emojis are often made up of zero width joiners. Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry forgot to tag you in my reply @CarlEdwards

Answer (score 0):

This way works i think:

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myText" placeholder=" ">

<button id="but1" onclick="myFunctionA()">A</button>
<button id="but2" onclick="myFunctionB()">B</button>

<script>
  function myFunctionA() {
  document.getElementById("myText").placeholder = document.getElementById("myText").placeholder + "A";
}

function myFunctionB() {
  document.getElementById("myText").placeholder = document.getElementById("myText").placeholder + "B";
}

//And so on 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any doubts tell me